# How can I develop a process to have Apache send error logs to a web API?

Tags: apache, api, error-handling

As the questions says: How can I develop a process to have Apache send error logs to a web API?

My current thought is to write a script that will empty the error log and send it to the web API and have it run as a cron job. But I am wondering if any other methods exists? Surely someone must have had this idea before me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the logs to an external process like curl. Curl can deliver them to a web API. Add something like this to your apache configuration file:

```
ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/error.log  | /usr/bin/curl URL"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/access.log | /usr/bin/curl URL" extended_ncsa
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. Do you have any links for documentation on this subject? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Yeah sure here is some documentation on Apache Piped Logs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped.  You can learn about tee and curl by reading the man pages. http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl